# What's the difference between "on weekends" and "at weekends"?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "***on weekends***" and "***at weekends***"?

Answer (score 11):

Generally speaking:

- *On weekends* is used in American English (and in British English, but less often).
- *At weekends* is used in British English.

They have the same meaning.  They're both acceptable, although speakers of American English may not recognize the *at* version.

---

The following are search results from [GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/) for both terms.  The units were set to *per million* rather than *raw hits*, so that the frequencies would be directly comparable:

|  | Great Britain | United States |
| --- | --- | --- |
| at weekends | 2.37 | 0.05 |
| on weekends | 0.93 | 2.12 |

As you can see, both terms are used in British English, although there's a preference for the *at* version.  In contrast, American English very strongly favors the *on* version.

Answer (score -2):

“At” is generally used to refer to a point of time and “on” is used before a day. A weekend is maybe one, or in some cases, two days. So, “on” should be there before a weekend.

Comment: Can you edit to explain why you think this is the correct answer rather than the current answer which refers to different usage on the opposite sides of the Atlantic?